# windows 7, prob with Lenova

Tags: desktop, icons

I keep getting a message from Lenova that I am running out of disk space on my Lenova Recovery.  They suggest deleting files from my Recycle Bin....not the desk top icon, but the one containing all my deleted files.  Where do I find this and how do I clear it?